# HTML not working in KML file when uploaded to Google My Maps

Tags: html, kml

I've created a KML file and added some HTML in the `<description>` tag, between `<![CDATA[` and `]]>`. When I upload the kml file to Google My Maps, the content of the balloon is shown in plain text. Why is the HTML not working?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Folder>
      <name>Basins/areas</name>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Dutch North Sea</name>
        <description>
          <![CDATA[
     <p><a href="http://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/Chimney-Atlas-A15-3A.pptx" download>Download PowerPoint</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Visualization of vertical hydrocarbon migration in seismic data: Case studies from the Dutch North Sea</strong><br />
     Connolly, D., Interpretation, 3(3), SX21-SX27, 2015<br />
     <a href="https://library.seg.org/doi/abs/10.1190/INT-2015-0007.1" target="_blank">Visit webpage</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Using gas chimneys in seal integrity analysis: A discussion based on case histories</strong><br />
     Heggland, R., 2005 in P. Boult and J. Kaldi, eds., Evaluating fault and cap rock seals: AAPG Hedberg Series, no. 2, p.237 - 245<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/aapg_hedberg_2005_heggland_chimney_classification.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Detection of fluid migration pathways in seismic data: implications for fault seal analysis</strong><br />
     Ligtenberg, H., 2005. Basin Research, March 2005, volume 17, p.141-153<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/Ligtenberg_BasinResearch.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Hydrocarbon Migration and Accumulation Above Salt Domes - Risking of Prospects by the Use of Gas Chimneys</strong><br />
     Heggland, R., 2004. 24th Annual GCSSEPM Foundation Bob F. Perkins Research Conference, Salt-Sediment Interactions and Hydrocarbon Prospectivity: Concepts, Applications, and Case Studies for the 21st Century, December 5-8, 2004, Houston, Texas<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/GCSSEPM_2004_Heggland_Migration+salt.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Unravelling the petroleum system by enhancing fluid migration paths in seismic data using a neural network based pattern recognition technique</strong><br />
     Ligtenberg, H., 2003. Geofluids magazine, 3, November 2003, p.255-261<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/Ligtenberg_GeoFluids2003.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Sealing quality analysis of faults and formations by means of seismic attributes and neural networks</strong><br />
     Ligtenberg, H., 2003. EAGE Fault and Top Seal conference, Montpellier, France, September 2003. Extended abstract<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/Ligtenberg_Fault_and_Top_Seals.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Fluid migration path detection and its application to basin modelling</strong><br />
     Ligtenberg, H. and Thomsen, R. (Maersk Oil), 2003. 65th EAGE conference, Stavanger, Norway<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/Ligtenberg_EAGE2003.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Identifying faults and gas chimney using multiattributes and neural networks</strong><br />
     Meldahl, P. (Statoil), Heggland, R. (Statoil), Bril, A. and de Groot, P., 2001. The Leading Edge, May 2001<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/TLE_2001_Meldahl_CCint.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Seismic chimney interpretation examples from the North Sea and the Gulf of Mexico</strong><br />
     Heggland, R. (Statoil), Meldahl, P. (Statoil), de Groot, P. and Aminzadeh, F., 2000. American Oil & Gas Reporter, February 2000<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/OILGAS_2000_Heggland_CCint.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
          ]]>
        </description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>4.05395999999996,55.24468,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Gulf of Mexico</name>
        <description>
          <![CDATA[
     <p><strong>Tutorial Processing & Interpretation</strong><br />
     <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eh76P_VSyEw" target="_blank">View video</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Atlas of gas chimney occurrences associated with oil and gas fields and dry holes: Case studies from deepwater Gulf of Mexico</strong><br />
     Connolly, D., SEG Technical Program Expanded Abstracts p. 1668-1672, 2015<br />
     <a href="https://library.seg.org/doi/abs/10.1190/segam2015-5910718.1" target="_blank">Visit webpage</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Detecting Fault-Related Hydrocarbon Migration Pathways in Seismic Data: Implications for Fault-Seal, Presure, and Charge Prediction</strong><br />
     Connolly, D.L, Brouwer, F., Walraven, D., October 2008<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/detecting%20fault-related%20hc%20migration%20pathways%20in%20seismic%20data.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Using gas chimneys in seal integrity analysis: A discussion based on case histories</strong><br />
     Heggland, R., 2005 in P. Boult and J. Kaldi, eds., Evaluating fault and cap rock seals: AAPG Hedberg Series, no. 2, p.237 - 245<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/aapg_hedberg_2005_heggland_chimney_classification.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Detection of fluid migration pathways in seismic data: implications for fault seal analysis</strong><br />
     Ligtenberg, H., 2005. Basin Research, March 2005, volume 17, p.141-153<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/Ligtenberg_BasinResearch.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Definition of geohazards in exploration 3-D seismic data using attributes and neural-network analysis</strong><br />
     Heggland, R., 2004. AAPG Bulletin, Special Theme Issue: High-resolution studies of continental margin geology and geohazards Volume 88, No. 6, June 2004<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/AAPG_2004_Heggland_Geohazards.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Application of gas chimney technology in the Lamprea area, offshore GOM</strong><br />
     Alvarado, J., Aminzadeh, F. and Connolly, D., 2003. SEG annual meeting, Dallas. Extended abstract<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/Chimney_technology_Lamprea_SEG2003.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Geohazard detection and other applications of chimney cubes</strong><br />
     Aminzadeh, F., Connolly, D., Heggland, R. (Statoil), Meldahl, P. (Statoil) and de Groot, P., 2002. The leading Edge, July 2002, p.681-685<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/TLE_2002_Aminzadeh_CCint.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Seismic evidence of vertical fluid migration through faults, Applications of Chimney and Fault detection</strong><br />
     Heggland, R. (Statoil), 2002. AAPG Hedberg Conference, Vancouver, BC, Canada<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/AAPG-Vanc_2002_Heggland_CCint.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Identifying faults and gas chimney using multiattributes and neural networks</strong><br />
     Meldahl, P. (Statoil), Heggland, R. (Statoil), Bril, A. and de Groot, P., 2001. The Leading Edge, May 2001<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/TLE_2001_Meldahl_CCint.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Selecting and combining attributes to enhance detection of seismic objects</strong><br />
     de Groot, P., Ligtenberg, H., Meldahl, P. (Statoil) and Heggland, R. (Statoil), 2001. 63rd EAGE conference, Extended abstract, Amsterdam<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/eage_2001_degroot_obj.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Detection of seismic objects, the fastest way to do prospect and geohazard evaluation</strong><br />
     Heggland, R. (Statoil), Meldahl, P. (Statoil), de Groot, P. and Bril, A., 2001. 63rd EAGE conference, Extended abstract, Amsterdam<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/eage_2001_heggland_obj.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
     
     <p><strong>Seismic chimney interpretation examples from the North Sea and the Gulf of Mexico</strong><br />
     Heggland, R. (Statoil), Meldahl, P. (Statoil), de Groot, P. and Aminzadeh, F., 2000. American Oil & Gas Reporter, February 2000<br />
     <a href="https://static.dgbes.com/images/PDF/OILGAS_2000_Heggland_CCint.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a></p>
          ]]>
        </description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>-88.4125,28.67611,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Google My Maps does not parse HTML in KML files. You can manually put some enters between the text in Google My Maps. To do this, click on `EDIT`. In the edit mode, click on one of your markers. In the balloon of a marker, click on the edit icon. There, in you text you can put enters between text using `Shift` + `Enter`.

If you still want to use HTML in KML files, you can use Google Earth. I uploaded the above file to Google Earth and everything looks fine.